# Complex ordering in SQL Query: possibly using CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I have a complex prioritisation algorithm that I want to write in SQL to when return prioritised pages of data.

Some of these are prioritised according to fixed values, other are ordered by variable values. i.e.

```
// Initial sort on ATTR1 (value1/value2 is higher than value3)
if ATTR1 = value1 or value2
  then orderBy creationDate, then modifiedDate, then author
else if ATTR1 = value3
  then 
    // if ATTR1 = value3, do secondary sort on ATTR2 (value4 is higher than value5)
    if ATTR2 = value4
       then orderBy oldPriority, then modifiedDate, then creationDate, then author
    if ATTR2 = value5
       then orderBy creationDate, then modifiedDate
```

I have had a look at SQL CASE WHEN, but not sure how to make that work with the second level of attribute comparison.

Is CASE WHEN a suitable tool for achieving this?  Does anyone have any tips on dealing with the additional levels of complexity?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure this makes sense: if there are just 2 rows and one has ATTR1=value1 and the other has ATTR1=value3 and ATTR2=value4, which should be ordered first?

Comment: I added some comments into my original question :)

Comment: Apologies, sent that one too soon.  Rows should be prioritised by ATTR1 first (in this order value1, value2, value3) - so in your example ATTR1 = value1 will come first.  Then if ATTR1 = value 3, go on to do secondary sort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
ORDER BY attr1,
CASE WHEN ATTR1 IN (value1, value2)
       THEN TO_CHAR(creationDate,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') 
            || to_char(modifiedDate,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') || author
     WHEN ATTR1 = value3
       THEN attr2 || CASE WHEN ATTR2 = value4
                            THEN to_char(oldPriority,'99999')
                                 || to_char(modifiedDate,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
                                 || to_char(creationDate,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') 
                                 || author
                          WHEN ATTR2 = value5
                            THEN to_char(creationDate,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
                                 || to_char(modifiedDate,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
                          END
     END
```

I assumed that oldPriority was a NUMBER column, which may not be the case.  The point is to convert everything to strings that order correctly, using appropriate format masks.

Comment: Thank you for replying. What does the || do??

Comment: || is the string concatenation operator, i.e. 'a' || 'b' is 'ab'

Answer (score 0):

Making a couple small assumptions, it seems this should work:

```
order by
   case ATTR1
      when value1 then
         1
      when value2 then
         2
      when value3 then
         3
   end,
      when ATTR1 in (value1,value2) 
           or (ATTR1 = value3 and ATTR2 = value5) then
         creationDate
      else
         null
      end,
   case 
      when ATTR1 = value3 and ATTR2 = value4 then
         oldPriority
      else
         null
      end,
   modifiedDate,
   case
      when not (ATTR1 = value3 and ATTR2 = value5) then
          author
      else null
      end
```